# Show that $x^4-4$ isn't reducible over $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I know that $x^4-4 = (x^2)^{^2}-(2)^{^2}=(x^2-2)\cdot (x^2+2)$.

But, why isn't reducible over $\Bbb Q$?

However, the answer in my book says that it is not reducible. However, if I can separate in factors, I understand that it should be reducible. So I’m confused about the answer to my book.

Comment: Why do you think it would not be reducible?

Comment: The definition of *reducible* is that it can be factored in a "non-trivial" way. You have done it!

Comment: You provided a factoring, thereby proving that it is reducible.

Comment: You reduced it, and the factors are well within $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, so what's your question?

Comment: You factored it and $\pm 2 \in \mathbb Q$, thus it was reducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @lulu. However, the answer in my book says that it is not reducible. However, if I can separate in factors, I understand that it should be reducible. So I’m confused about the answer to my book.

Comment: Perhaps the authors were thinking of $x^4+1$.  In any case, $x^4-1$ is obviously reducible.

Comment: @lulu Not only $x^4-1$, but also $x^4-4$. It seems that typos here are quite frequent.

Comment: Fernando, are you sure that the book says $x^4-4$? Perhaps it is $x^3-4$ or $x^4-3$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Indeed.  To be sure, I intended $x^4-4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde - yes, it says $x^4-4$.

Comment: Answers in the back of textbooks are created thus:  Professor writes book. Professor throws manuscript at his worst grad student and tells him to work out all the exercises.  Grad students powers through the boring assignment as quickly as possible.  Publisher has a deadline and there's no chance for review.   It's a fertile ground for typos.  Sometimes they multiply after publication.

Comment: @B.Goddard. Thanks for your feedback. This really must be a wrong of the author of the book.

Comment: the neat bit is that $x^4 +4$ is also reducible.